# Squared Mahalanobis distance function in Python returning array - why?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, mahalanobis

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
def Mahalanobis(x, covariance_matrix, mean):
    x = np.array(x)
    mean = np.array(mean)
    covariance_matrix = np.array(covariance_matrix)
    return (x-mean)*np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix)*(x.transpose()-mean.transpose())

#variables x and mean are 1xd arrays; covariance_matrix is a dxd matrix
#the 1xd array passed to x should be multiplied by the (inverted) dxd array
#that was passed into the second argument
#the resulting 1xd matrix is to be multiplied by a dx1 matrix, the transpose of 
#[x-mean], which should result in a 1x1 array (a number)
```

But for some reason I get a matrix for my output when I enter the parameters

```
Mahalanobis([2,5], [[.5,0],[0,2]], [3,6])
```

output:

```
out[]: array([[ 2. ,  0. ],
              [ 0. ,  0.5]])
```

It seems my function is just giving me the inverse of the 2x2 matrix that I input in the 2nd argument.

Comment: Split that long return expression into multiple statements. Print the result of each line after it executes. Then share the output here if you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of assuming that the * operator is doing matrix multiplication. This is not true in Python/numpy (see http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). I broke it down into intermediate steps and used the dot function

```
import numpy as np
def Mahalanobis(x, covariance_matrix, mean):

    x = np.array(x)
    mean = np.array(mean)
    covariance_matrix = np.array(covariance_matrix)

    t1 = (x-mean)
    print(f'Term 1 {t1}')

    icov = np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix)
    print(f'Inverse covariance {icov}')

    t2 = (x.transpose()-mean.transpose())
    print(f'Term 2 {t2}')

    mahal = t1.dot(icov.dot(t2))

    #return (x-mean)*np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix).dot(x.transpose()-mean.transpose())
    return mahal

#variables x and mean are 1xd arrays; covariance_matrix is a dxd matrix
#the 1xd array passed to x should be multiplied by the (inverted) dxd array
#that was passed into the second argument
#the resulting 1xd matrix is to be multiplied by a dx1 matrix, the transpose of 
#[x-mean], which should result in a 1x1 array (a number)


Mahalanobis([2,5], [[.5,0],[0,2]], [3,6])
```

produces

```
Term 1 [-1 -1]
Inverse covariance [[2.  0. ]
 [0.  0.5]]
Term 2 [-1 -1]
Out[9]:    2.5
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was extremely helpful. Going forward it'll be useful to know that the * operand doesn't work for matrix multiplication!

Answer (score 0):

One can use `scipy`'s `mahalanobis()` function to verify:

```
import scipy.spatial, numpy as np

scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis([2,5], [3,6], np.linalg.inv([[.5,0],[0,2]]))
# 1.5811388300841898
1.5811388300841898**2 # squared Mahalanobis distance
# 2.5000000000000004

def Mahalanobis(x, covariance_matrix, mean):
  x, m, C = np.array(x), np.array(mean), np.array(covariance_matrix)
  return (x-m)@np.linalg.inv(C)@(x-m).T

Mahalanobis([2,5], [[.5,0],[0,2]], [3,6])
# 2.5 

np.isclose(
   scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis([2,5], [3,6], np.linalg.inv([[.5,0],[0,2]]))**2, 
   Mahalanobis([2,5], [[.5,0],[0,2]], [3,6])
)
# True
```